# Check if weekday is in the past DateTime c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working on a weather application and I want that when the user input "Tuesday" and the present day is Wednesday, it will give me the weather of the coming Tuesday instead.

Any help please?

Comment: @DavidPilkington Apparently nothing it seems

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get "next Tuesday" but the exact solution depends on the answer to this question:

> If today is Tuesday, and the user types in Tuesday, do you want today, or next week?

If the answer is "Today", then the following two solutions will work:

```
public static DateTime NextDateByDayOfWeek1(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    var daysUntil = ((dow - DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7;
    return DateTime.Today.AddDays(daysUntil);
}

public static DateTime NextDateByDayOfWeek2(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    var date = DateTime.Today;
    while (date.DayOfWeek != dow)
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    return date;
}
```

If the answer is "next week", you should simply add 1 day to the date you use in the methods:

```
public static DateTime NextDateByDayOfWeek1(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    var daysUntil = ((dow - DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7;
    return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 + daysUntil);
}

public static DateTime NextDateByDayOfWeek2(DayOfWeek dow)
{
    var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    while (date.DayOfWeek != dow)
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    return date;
}
```

You can even generalize them:

```
public static DateTime NextDateByDayOfWeek1(DateTime startDate, DayOfWeek dow)
{
    var daysUntil = ((dow - startDate.DayOfWeek) + 7) % 7;
    return startDate.AddDays(daysUntil);
}

public static DateTime NextDateByDayOfWeek2(DateTime startDate, DayOfWeek dow)
{
    var date = startDate;
    while (date.DayOfWeek != dow)
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    return date;
}
```

The `startDate` will be returned if it is already of the correct day of the week. To get "next week's date", simply use `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)` when calling it, otherwise use `DateTime.Today`.

---

Why two solutions?

Because the "worst case scenario" for the loop-based solution is 6 iterations, whereas the one using the remainder operator might need some documentation to be understood by people who reads this code. Pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the day is selected, but you should be able to use DateTime.DayOfWeek

```
var datetimeNow = DateTime.Now; // Wednesday

var selectedDay = Datetime.Now.AddDays(-1); //Tuesday

if(datetimeNow.DayOfWeek < selectedDay.DayOfWeek)
    selectedDay = selectedDay.AddDays(7); // Will then be the coming tuesday
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`DayOfWeek` is an `int` based `enum`, (sunday=0 - saturday = 7) so it can be used to calculate the days until your desired day.

```
var input = DayOfWeek.Monday;

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int days = input - today.DayOfWeek;
days = days < 0 ? days+7 : days; // fix it if we past that day already.

var newDate = today.AddDays(days);
```